# Button click call PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a solution for on click button call PHP function in the same PHP file, PHP function internally executes a Perl script as well as downloads a file using ftp.
(my Perl script is executing and my ftp download works fine) only when I click button it's not calling PHP function). I found many other posting didn't find the solution which I am looking. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

below is my sample PHP code

```
<?php
    function getFile(){
      exec("/../myperlscript.pl  parameters");// 
      //some code for ftp file download( which is working )
    }
<!--
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
  getFile();
} 
 -->
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                sucess: getFile
            });
        });
</script>
<form method="post">
   <input type="button" name="getFile" value="getFile">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you used Ajax before? What about jquery? Also, do you know the difference between server-side and client-side?

Answer (score 1):

The are a lot of things that you are doing wrong and I am feeling like you are not clear about PHP, jquery and even AJAX.

Since you want to send / retrieve POST data via AJAX on button click and without refreshing the page, you don't need the form element.

Instead, try to understand how Ajax works from the following

```
<?php
  function getFile($filename) {
      echo "working, contents of $filename will be displayed here";

      //terminate php script to prevent other content to return in ajax data
      exit();
  }

  if (isset($_POST['getfile']) && $_POST['getfile'] === "true") { 
      getFile($_POST['filename']);
  }
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#getFile").click (function(){
          $.post("index.php", // current php file name
          {
              // post data to be sent
              getfile: "true",
              filename: "file1"
          },
          function(data, status){
              // callback / function to be executed after the Ajax request
              $("#fileContent").text(data);
          });
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="getFile">Get File</button>
<p id="fileContent"></p>
```